# Change inner value in paragraph jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I would like to change two values in a paragraph, the comment, and the source text, but my jQuery seems only to change the comment, and the source is left empty.

```
<div class="container">
<p class="lead custom_bg" id="comment"> updateme!
    <code id="source"> updateme2!</code>
</p>
</div>
```

jQuery ajax

```
success: function(response){
         $('#comment').text(response['comment']);
         $('#source').text(response['source']);
     }
```

Of my understanding the .text attribute seems to change all the text inside that paragraph.

Comment: simply wrap `updateme!` in a span or `p` tag, then do your stuff in the js  ```$('#comment p').text(response['comment']);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because by setting the `text()` of the `#comment` you're destroying all the HTML within that element, so `#source` actually no longer exists.

To fix this issue you need to instead change the value of the first text node within `#comment` only, like this:

```js
var response = {
  comment: 'comment',
  source: 'source'
}

$('#comment').contents()[0].nodeValue = response['comment'];
$('#source').text(response['source']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p class="lead custom_bg" id="comment"> updateme!
    <code id="source"> updateme2!</code>
  </p>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can wrap the target text in its own `span` which can be targeted directly, like this:

```js
var response = {
  comment: 'comment',
  source: 'source'
}

$('#comment span').text(response['comment']);
$('#source').text(response['source']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p class="lead custom_bg" id="comment"> 
    <span>updateme!</span>
    <code id="source"> updateme2!</code>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. It create the element you need in the second line

```
$('#comment').html(response['comment']+'<code id="source"></code>');         
$('#source').html(response['source']);
```

Edited: .text() => .html()

Answer (score 0):

The HTML gets destroyed when you set text, so an option is to store the inner html i.e. the `#source` and append it again after setting the text.

I replaced responce part with filler text so you will need to re-add the variables.

```js
var keepMe = $('#source');
$('#comment').text("hi");
$('#comment').append(keepMe);
$('#source').text("hi2");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<p class="lead custom_bg" id="comment"> updateme!
    <span id="source"> updateme2!</span>
</p>
</div>
```